# C# Console application dying when ran with .exe file

Tags: c#, xna, console-application

I'm making a game in XNA, and it's a multiplayer game, consisting of two solutions: One is the XNA Game, and another is the server done in C# console application.

The server uses a reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework

When I run the server through VS13, it runs just as expected.
But whenever I run the server through the .EXE file in the debug folder, the console kills itself immidiately.

The way it should be is that the console outputs some string,
and then runs in a while(true) method in a thread that seeks for new players (Game uses TCP for network purposes).

I can give the source code in private if needed.

Comment: When you run it from the Debug folder, are you running it on the same machine as well?

Comment: Run the executable from the console (not double click) and you will get the exception.

Comment: I ran it from cmd (correct me if i'm wrong, shift+rc-> copy as path, paste into cmd and run?) and it still doesn't work. It like parses the path, changes the title for a moment and returns to the previous state. and for mageos, yes, same machine.

Comment: Does it need any resources from files? Does it run if you start it from the solution folder with `bin\debug\file.exe`? You probably are catching and throwing away all exceptions, or not writing out errors, if there is no error about anything.

Comment: it probobably needs some files, for example the dll file and some other files, but i do run it from the bin\debug folder

Comment: Also, I tried wrapping all the main function in a try-catch block and CW the exception message and the console closed immidiately like before.

Comment: _[Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help)_

Comment: @MickyDuncan I am more than aware that I bring very little information, but this is really all i have. I don't get an exception nor does it really gives me anything. It literally dies out on me the moment the file is ran. It runs fine though VS, but when I run the file it acts like I stated. As I've said, I'm willing to give the source code (thought dropbox or email, whatever anyone wants) to try and check that out. This really is all that is happening.

Comment: If there's like no specific reason, I guess that what I'm asking is for any common things that might cause this kind of behavior, that's all.

Comment: Post your console app source code in your question above please. Also, list the references the console app is making.

Comment: The code is rather long, I'll simply upload it to dropbox and give the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xn032d0d9ldwh3y/AADU8fse9QK_LC_oQI0om6fwa?dl=0  This is the whole server folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is identified.
When I got the server to my comp from where it was before, there was a mixup with the xna reference and the target platform. So I changed the target platform and apperantly it made a new folder inside the bin folder called x86 so eventually the debug folder that was inside it worked.
What was in what I tried all this time is the build I did before I even changed the target platform so that why it did nothing - the main was empty ;D